# Linking custom object files with Cabal

Tags: c++, haskell, linker, cabal

In a custom cabal hook I generated object files (*.o) which I want to pass to the linker. How do I do this idiomatically?

**Solution**
Don Stewart's answer goes in the right direction. Currently I do the following:

```
$ runhaskell Setup.lhs build --ld-options="PATHS TO .o FILES"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Cabal documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Cabal/1.10.1.0/doc/html/Distribution-Simple-UserHooks.html) for `UserHooks`, it looks like you'll need to add a `buildHook`, by specifying additional [build flags](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Cabal/1.10.1.0/doc/html/Distribution-Simple-Setup.html#t%3aBuildFlags), that add your .o files to the [buildFlags](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Cabal/1.10.1.0/doc/html/Distribution-Simple-Setup.html#t%3aBuildFlags) for ld.

---

As an aside, you should be aware that generating custom .o files is highly unusual, and likely to make your build fragile. Is there a particular reason why Cabal is unable to generate these .o files itself?

Comment: dons everywhere :) I am writing C++ bindings for a library and passing the wrapper c++ files to Cabal (via 'c-sources') gives me running garbage, which means that Cabal needs to invoke a proper C++ compiler to generate the .o files.

Comment: Linking seems to take place within the 'buildHook' phase, but I can't simply pass modified BuildFlags to the default buildHook -- they are simply being ignored (at least the part of BuildFlags which interests me). But passing the parameters as command line flags kinda solves this problem for now, so thanks for the pointers. Regarding the wiki page: This solution seems to be even more unreasonable, it looks pretty gcc specific to me.

Comment: Could you add your solution to the question, for posterity?